# JAVA: Does anyone have a working link to this old drag and drop demo?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

the web demo is here:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorialJWS/uiswing/misc/examples/DragPictureDemo.jnlp

the old tutorial link was here http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/examples/index.html

obviously the tutorial link isn't working anymore, but i was wondering if maybe had something saved in your favorites that replaced this, or something similar?

tyia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/index.html